# Спецификация SVG 1.1 на русском языке

Tags: svg

Где в Интернете можно найти спецификацию SVG 1.1 или SVG 1.2 от W3C.org на русском языке? Сейчас читаю [спецификацию на английском](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/), но так как сроки очень поджимают, решил спросить, возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: Мне кажется, что спецификации пишут только на английском, потому что хоть малейшее изменение и придется переводить на все остальные поддерживаемые языки.  
Вряд ли найдете.

Comment: Я понимаю, что спецификации пишут на английском, но возможно, что кто-то перевел спецификацию на русский для своих нужд.

Comment: Предлагаю вам принять ответ Alexandr_TT, так как "ссылка умерла". Alexandr_TT действительно отвечает на вопрос.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**update 23.06.2019 г.**

Добавлен пункт 12.

> Ответ не будет строго отвечать на поставленный вопрос по простой
> причине, что нет перевода на русский `W3C` спецификации `SVG`.

Но будет иметь практическую пользу для людей, которые хотят начать изучать SVG и получить информацию на источники учебной литературы и полезные ссылки на нашем сайте, посвященные некоторым сложным теоретическим вопросам.

1. Вадим Дунаев  ["Основы SVG"](https://docplayer.ru/25925031-Osnovy-svg-chto-takoe-svg-vadim-dunaev.html) ... [скачать](https://yadi.sk/i/DYrw4gtGEgr9kQ)

Для начала изучения вполне достаточно. Чувствуется, что писал книгу сильный практик. Кратко, но ёмко всё изложено. Множество примеров, показывающих самую суть. Объем книги небольшой, но всё основное, что нужно есть. От простого к сложному. Практически сразу вместе с книгой можно начинать писать свои примеры. Книга в формате `pdf` выше ссылка на скачивание книги.

2. [Как взаимодействуют между собой viewport и viewBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)

Самый сложный для понимания и одновременно самый нужный, фундаментальный раздел SVG без изучения которого, невозможно создавать адаптивные приложения.

3. [Поиск ошибок в приложениях SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/825532/28748)

Практические приемы по диагностированию и предотвращению ошибок при создании приложений SVG

4. [Как правильно написать формулу path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/831351/28748)

   Приведены различные формы записи `<path>` с комментариями из теории патчей. Практические примеры написания патчей.
5. [Как нарисовать автомобиль с помощью команд SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/787247/28748)

Это учебный пример. Шаг за шагом будут прорисовываться детали автомобиля и по мере продвижения легко будет понять, как применяются на практике основные команды svg: `line`, `rect`, `circle`, `path`

6. [SVG фильтры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/755510/28748)

Подробно рассматривается вопрос работы с фильтрами SVG `feColorMatrix`

7. [Помогите с dasharray и dashoffset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761733/28748)

Рассматривается вопрос `in-depth` `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset` от самого простого случая к сложному. Прочитав статью вы можете самостоятельно делать свои примеры, которые востребованы в вебдизайне.

8. [Спрайты SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

Раздел имеет десятки вопросов-ответов, в каком-нибудь топике из этого раздела вы точно найдете ответ на свой вопрос по спрайтам.

9. [Практические примеры применения масок svg?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919187/28748)

   Теория масок,- кратко и доступно для новичков SVG.
   Большое количество примеров
10. [Как оптимизировать svg код, полученный из векторного редактора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/935167/28748)
11. [Практически весь SVG в примерах и задачах](http://oreillymedia.github.io/svg-essentials-examples/)

**update 23.06.2019 г.**

12. [Как рассчитать матрицу SVG-преобразования по значениям rotate / translate / scale?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/995586/28748)

Comment: Добавил объемный сборник практических примеров по SVG. Можно брать оттуда код и экспериментировать с ним, многие примеры интерактивны. На мой взгляд, для начинающих изучать SVG это просто клад!

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG

Да, прибудет с Вами хорошее настроение!!!

Comment: Это хорошо, но, к сожалению, не спецификация, а лишь справочник

Comment: Да, я знаю. Я подошел по-человечески. Возможно человек изучает возможности и справочник будет в таком случае подходящим. Спецификация хорошо, но, как отметили в комментариях перевод пока в долгом ящике :-(

Answer (score 2):

По SVG так и не нашел, но нашел другие спецификации W3C на русском - [Русские переводы документов World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)](http://web.archive.org/web/20150627042654/http://w3.hotbox.ru/).
Нашел отличную документацию по `SVG` на русском языке, возможно, многим будет полезно - [SVG синтаксис](http://graphing.ru/i/svg-syntax/).

Comment: ссылка умерла и даже в веб архивах тоже в 2015 году, ниже в доп. ответе опубликовал свежую информацию