# Изменить цвет SVG - изображения

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Вношу правки в верстку сайта на `Laravel`, весь `CSS` код билдится из `SCSS`.

Код добавления SVG картинки выглядит так:

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/heart.svg" class="red heart-icon"></object>
```

Почему то не срабатывает

```css
.red {
  fill: #ff0000;
}
```

До этого верстал только на голом HTML + CSS сейчас пытаюсь постигнуть новые фишки, сразу видны пробелы в знаниях. Можете подсказать что я делаю не так? Я так понял беда в том, что сначала картинка подтягивается на сайт в своем исходном, а затем я пытаюсь его изменить обычным CSS. Обязательно прибегать к помощи JS?

Внес исправления, смена цвета заработала, но 
1) :hover таким же образом прописанный не работает. В чем может быть дело?
2) object оборачивается в ссылку, но по клику на него переход не происходит, как это можно исправить?

```html
<div class="cell small-12 medium-3 flex-container">
    [...]
    <a class="more text-uppercase flex-container align-justify align-middle width-100" href="{{ route('article.view', [$article->slug]) }}" title="{{ $article->title }}">
 <span>Читать дальше</span>
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/external-link-symbol.svg" class="icon-after"></object>
    </a>
</div>

//код svg теперь выглядит так

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../css/app.css"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 511.626 511.627" class="icon readmore-icon light-gray" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g>
  <path d="..."/>
  <path d="..."/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Это не пробелы в знаниях, а пробелы в технологиях) Проблема в том, что svg работает как отдельный документ, и кажется что js тоже не поможет. Есть поход через якорную ссылку указывать стиль внутри svg и там менять цвет, но не работает в сафари и может еще где-то.

Comment: Странно, читал много статей, где явно говорилось что именно в таком формате как у меня svg-изображение реально перекрасить, только почему то именно в моем случае их примеры не работали

Comment: @СергейКурамшин добавьте код иконки svg, от её кода, точнее её стилей на 100% зависит решение ваших проблем. Пока информации мало, вы привели код стандартного добавления svg в HTML

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Наверное полезно дать ответ и на более широкий круг вопросов стилизации иконок.
Есть очень полезная статья  *`Styling SVG <use> Content with CSS`* - [перевод](http://prgssr.ru/development/oformlenie-soderzhimogo-use-v-svg-s-pomoshyu-css.html),-    [оригинал](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/)

Для решения вашей задачи, полезен раздел статьи - **Каскадирование стилей**

Из этого раздела можно сделать вывод, что наивысшим приоритетом обладает *внутренние стили svg.*

```
<path style="fill:red; stroke:blue;" d="M100,100 ... />"
```

**Чтобы устранить доминирование приоритета внутренних стилей svg необходимо:**

1. Удалить в коде иконки все атрибуты стилизации у патчей, полигонов и т.д все инлайновые стили - `fill`, `stroke`
2. Добавить во внешней таблице стилей `path{ fill:inherit; stroke:inherit; }`
3. Стилизацию иконок уже делать в таблице стилей на уровне классов иконок
4. В шапку файлов *.svg иконок добавить строчку, указывающую на внешнюю таблицу стилей

   `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>`
5. Файл таблицы стилей и файлы SVG лучше разместить в одной папке, так как браузеры чувствительны к этому, больше других `chrome`

### Update

Добавляете спрайт с иконками в HTML

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/external-link-symbol.svg" class="icon-after"></object>
```

вызываете иконку из спрайта по её `id` с помощью команды `<use>`

```
<div>
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 511.626 511.627" class="icon readmore-icon light-gray" xml:space="preserve">
<use xlink:href="external-link-symbol.svg#idIcon" />
</svg>
</div>
```

[Вот более подробно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/666763/28748) о нюансах добавления и стилизации иконки из спрайта

Смотрите, пробуйте варианты, уверен, что у вас получится. Так как это получается у многих, кто хочет добиться результата.

Comment: В моем случае картинки в формате svg просто лежат в папке images, такие мне отдал дизайнер. А так как я в первый раз имею дело с svg то даже не знаю как их встраивать. Почитал несколько статей, в одной было написано, что вставка через object со ссылкой на картинку - является одним из лучших решений. Как то так. 

Можно ли поменять стиль если грузить просто картинкой.svg?

Comment: Воспользовался вашей инструкцией и все получилось) Спасибо большое. Надоедает, правда идти по всем svg и дописывать xml-stylesheet, но зато раз и навсегда. Можно делать с иконками что угодно. Упустил из виду, что svg это просто path'ы прописанные в коде)

Comment: Ховер таким же образом прописанный не работает(

Comment: @СергейКурамшин код иконки добавь в вопрос пожалуйста, не понимаю, почему до сих пор не сделали этого. Проще же будет понять причину

Comment: @СергейКурамшин Видите, как слова можно понимать по разному.:) Я аж три ответа написал, основываясь на ваших комментариях. А был бы код весь сразу в вопросе, то был бы один, конкретный ответ сразу. Сейчас вижу, что вы смешали два способа вместе 1. инлайн - непосредственное добавление svg кода в Html и добавление спрайта с иконками svg через тег `object`. Не стоит их смешивать или инлайн или `object`

Comment: инлайн я не вставляю в сам шаблон, я подтягиваю его в object, я просто вставил его содержимое для ознакомления

Comment: @СергейКурамшин сейчас добавлю update, как использовать иконки из спрайта

Answer (score 5):

### Ответ #2

Для быстрого решения проблем со стилизацией иконок.
Данная техника подойдет, если нужно быстро добавить иконки в свой проект, которые можно раскрасить в любой цвет из внешнего файла `CSS`.
  Причём иконки высокого качества, практически полный набор на все случаи.
 Иконки адаптивны и не теряют качества при масштабировании, так как это иконки SVG из которых состоит символьный шрифт  - [**Google Material Icons**](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html)

Подключение шрифта:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

Выбирать иконки по названиям можно [здесь](https://material.io/icons/)

Выбираем нужную иконку с именем - `favorite`

Подключение иконки к HTML странице:

`<i class="material-icons red">favorite</i>`, где

`material-icons` - общий класс для всех иконок
`red` - дополнительный класс, задающий цвет окраски иконки

Ниже пример с тремя одинаковыми иконками, которые раскрашены в разные цвета 
Добавлена анимация увеличения иконок при `hover`.

```css
.material-icons {
transform: scale(2);
}
i {
  margin: 100px 50px 50px 80px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
i:hover {
  transform: scale(10);
}

.red{color:red}
.green{color:yellowgreen}
.blue{color: dodgerblue}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">        
<i class="material-icons red">favorite</i>
<i class="material-icons green">favorite</i> 
<i class="material-icons blue">backup</i>
```

Размер иконок также можно менять, здесь удвоенный исходный размер:

```
.material-icons {
transform: scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Александр, а иконки обязательно помещать в тег `i` или можно реализовать в любом теге?

Comment: @Air попробуй, я пробовал в тег `<p>` - получилось, но решил для себя, что лучше в `<i>`, как в оригинале

Comment: Ну видать можно)))

Comment: Вот именно такие иконки были до меня) Сказали поменять на десигнерские) А десигнерские являют собой просто картинку в формате SVG и никакие манипуляции с ней не канают(

Answer (score 4):

### Ответ #3

Ответ на комментарии

> Вот именно такие иконки были до меня) Сказали поменять на
>   десигнерские) А десигнерские являют собой просто картинку в формате
>   SVG и никакие манипуляции с ней не канают
>
> Ховер таким же образом прописанный не работает

### Стилизация изображений в формате image/png;base64 при наведении курсора

Представьте 
такую ситуацию,- дизайнер нарисовал очень красивую картинку, лого и т.д. Выполнил вашу просьбу, чтобы она была в векторном формате.
 Но, рисовал её в растровом редакторе и сохранил её, как бы вектор, в формате base64.
То есть встроил растр в векторный формат. Обычная стилизация не работает.
Перерисовать вам в чистом векторе затруднительно.
 В этом случае можно  заменить стилизацию на обработку SVG фильтрами.

**Основная идея** - в исходном состоянии на изображение накладывается один фильтр

```
<filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
```

А при наведении курсора применяются другие цветные фильтры `id="RedFilter"`, `id="GreenFilter"`

```css
.R1:hover {
filter:url(#RedFilter);
} 

.G1:hover {
filter:url(#GreenFilter);
}
.B1:hover {
filter:url(#BlueFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="150" viewBox="0 -30 400 150" style="border:1px solid grey;"> 

  <defs>
 <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
 <filter id="GreenFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
 
 <filter id="BlueFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
 
 <filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 


   <image id="Building" width="100" height="100"  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABcCAYAAACYyxCUAAAABGdBTUEAA1teXP8meAAABqhJREFUeAHtXc+LHUUQ3qhIREFFRA9GV8QfyAp78JYg8eZlwaN6yf4H6kGQnHKQ4M38AR5yih48CHvxZPaw3jws6EEPgiQS4g/wiYoiMfH7wtbwvXLeTL95Mz09u1XQTFV3dXd1ffOqpntmk2NrZdK7MIvF6C4w95pwiK43sJY/dT13qBD8+B4IQMbHYM6CAGTOHeMLjM0l0t0wSnPGsRKN7MGmO90610oFhL/cUm3rAYdqCN5oc+uMkFX5pgwmACkDh8qKuZ9LVVs+8xVMPOvM/MPJ90BmjDY6D+YFE3C9hPKRyP+C/0tk9uUYSjsqgKcNtMWI/TmOEXMhixHnpx0LaaqA/IYV7blVzZx8H2RdH/soXYWgY3CTpqCyL8doIoKhY7A/xzE6DoYlmSJkJbsqj2IAksfPybMEIMmuyqMYgOTxc/IsAUiyq/IoBiB5/Jw8iz4WJncqQPF+2HDK2aGPrGzy+xD2UToBQcdI2Ydof/K6r6Gcsg+h3uToHCy+dRRLhKzC7tUApDBApppDeAyiZ0h0qx5ZUOZZlL5HYbzXPHIFMosRQ6SeQ7GvnoVRT3MOZdqgRzLsz3GMeMPrTc/5fd4x3dvXqQJCR2zNrWRtre0sawf66lAeLL4vYxBQfTCgb/xZ1q+iT5aHi3tS13aWxflpx0JS9BYqRUM+DwQg+XydNFMAkuSmfEoBSD5fJ80UgCS5KZ9SAJLP10kzBSBJbsqnNNV9CDdX/nme+wiluo2htr8O4aRUpGwMRf02yw8Wlt0Y+jHm5KkCwh2vbvLmFpUoPA49llWocdfdZeAIWV28NmCfAGRA53YZeqohi2dZ8aFcF8QH6sNEqod6nKbtcFGTL/XjQzl6IajZA5FDmv2TvTUlh2zDqvUGy75H20VpJ8j6gbE0Vew/4G5WUjCVB1IAOQPt01WP/zO7qLoo1QSk7QNjbuICEHGasRGyzBOFXAOQQoAwM1JClunalfGfxehvMDpO64t86HMfoY+h/uMAG3vRte7oRN+Hs98kP5RTRy5avK/ni/7rUvkjeP0YgOc7F6S9jn0LlfvS4D8OkKZatu5wsVaxofINtLGsQo1/DdVl4AhZXbw2YJ8AZEDndhk6JWTxA2KNzz9A/kYm+xn8psjPgtcQJk0VSx0ln1P4WKxz8t2G/gEm8w/7KKW8D2HuMboChsUo5X2IP/L3dvtcyBteb/rW/JoCyDUM+p1ZjesnKB+LvAFecwbBeEra69h3UKkOr8spOqcfk47YcgPPnMw+ur4dyOrQ+FDOOSzEGg/oz6mmOapyeyAAye3xlvk0xi5S5QfJjMdGr4L51ARcfXyXpoWszzEfQlNzCnMU5zHaAPOeCbhqfpHq6bPxCykMwwAkACnMA4WZo39hZKb5QznuGXQj9wzkp00ZV79pk6Zk1v/16rfoqZvPnyB/LqM9Cv4Vkck+5GTapevj+dckN4ZciCb7JyA/h2JEZ2iSt/pVrroL5ziPoagNX0NmMWLbiyYcXGnnMsSP5FhWIYLcK0UO6dWdqw8WgKzuw15HYIz14edN1GmOeAnywzIrP2BgGZL8S7BfMNkXMuF18J+JTPaGk30uPI92DTGXIPM8y4gHg8xlRnW5kedhSmch8FzNyOdC7yvOTzsWEmOxxmoqEoxNMgdEMDxo1jbU1S+E82zIZHT+lyKTnTmZNuva9A0lVa+i7JE5II6pm1P2bVs3wdAx2F9vjOOQWZIpQlayq/IoBiB5/Jw8C3+WrzltPuLy0daI4WNsog1q0/OQt51RF5w8SbEOEG4CHyhsNQTkEbGJ/wz5tshkDwUgEbIcqmOLAcjYCLj5GbL2Xd3vkPVxbxPy2CFs5uzk8/41FKV1FcA/iaL/w4KeY1H1BMopMgeUsg8xXbvqvoZ1KfsQ61t71cO3WgVUXkY5vagxU/0u5nm5Za5zrv0M5HVXV7wYIaswiAKQwgBhDpkiMacxtymtqwB+qSML13c0caqAEAzmtkNHEbIKgzQACUAK80Bh5hylX8gWfP+gFL7A4j5smaL9ye+h9EpHCZBeHTfUYAHIUJ7tOG4A0tFxQ3UbYh+yD2PfbjH4A7T7jV1Ll5WbefCn78xvdhhR+7M7DyR7pSEAmcHC3RYrqZOb6Dz9AKHL/L7/rS6DNPWJkNXknRHaApARnN40ZQDS5J0R2gKQEZzeNGUA0uSdEdoCkBGc3jRlANLknRHaApARnN40ZQDS5J0R2gKQEZzeNGXK0QnPppahFP0UHZ3T68/QuKsKCTz79E3erpXH/w/ZozT+IeSLqwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg"/>   
   </defs> 
    
   <use class="R1" id="BuildingRed" xlink:href="#Building" x="20" y="0"   ></use> 
   <use class="G1" id="BuildingGreen" xlink:href="#Building" x="150" y="0"  ></use> 
    <use class="B1" id="BuildingBlue" xlink:href="#Building" x="280" y="0"  ></use>
   
   
</svg>
```

Более подробно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/755510/28748)

Answer (score 1):

**Хотите вставить на страницу файл `svg` через тег `img` или `object` и, при этом, без танцев с бубном во внешней таблице стилей, изменять его цвет?**

Опытным путем я нашел следующее решение, которое, на мой взгляд, является наилучшим и наиболее удобным. Единственное, что стоит отметить - **этот способ изменяет цвет всего `svg`**

##### 1. Используйте тег `img` или `object` вместе с классом для файла `svg`:

```html
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.svg" alt="">

<!-- Или -->

<object class="logo" data="images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

##### 2. Посетите любой сайт, который генерирует цвет для свойства `filter` из `css` (ниже привел пару ссылок):

- https://angel-rs.github.io/css-color-filter-generator/
- https://cssfilterconverter.com/

По итогу из, например, `#087A64` получаем такое:

```css
brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(32%) sepia(10%) saturate(7304%) hue-rotate(135deg) brightness(100%) contrast(94%)
```

##### 3. В вашем файле `css` для класса тега, в моем случае это `logo`, указываем преобразованный цвет:

```css
.logo {
  filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(32%) sepia(10%) saturate(7304%) hue-rotate(135deg) brightness(100%) contrast(94%);
}
```

#### НО! Это же выглядит страшно.

По этой причине будем использовать корневые (пользовательские) переменные. Можно их указывать в отдельном файле и потом его импортировать или сразу в вашем файле указывать.

##### 4. Создайте переменную и поместите туда весь полученный ранее код, а потом исправьте ваш класс:

```css
:root {
  --basic-green: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(32%) sepia(10%) saturate(7304%) hue-rotate(135deg) brightness(100%) contrast(94%);
}

.logo {
  filter: var(--basic-green);
}
```

**Всё, готово!**