# Адаптировать изображение под вьюпорт. Сохранение пропорций

Tags: html, css, адаптивность

Нужно, чтобы элемент img, сохраняя пропорции и находясь по центру, принимал минимально необходимый размер для заполнения родительского блока.
[image: для примера]

При попытке установить min-height и min-width по 100% изображение растягивается на всю свою величину, выходя за границы родителя сверх необходимого (да ещё и только от левого верхнего угла).
Возможно ли это без скриптов?

Comment: `background`? `background-size: cover`? `background-position: 0 0`?

Comment: Ничего из этого.
Цитирую "нужно, чтобы элемент img..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `object-fit: cover;` и `object-position: center;` например:

```css
div.a {width: 400px; height: 200px;}
div.b {width: 200px; height: 400px;}
div {border: 1px solid black;}
div img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <img src="http://volyninfo.com/core/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/70664-300x206.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="b">
  <img src="http://volyninfo.com/core/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/70664-300x206.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Идеально. Спасибо.
Не понимаю, почему я этих свойств до сих пор не знал...

Comment: Честно говоря, я недавно тут и тоже периодически возникает ощущение - как я раньше этого не знал. Давно работаю, а оказывается столько дыр в знаниях... Сам эти свойства узнал не так давно...

Comment: только имейте ввиду, что в ие эти св-ва не поддерживаются

Comment: То есть для него всё-таки придётся делать решение на JS?

Comment: Да, точно, как обычно с IE проблемы. Можно библиотеку подключить, как тут советуют: https://html5book.ru/svoystva-object-fit-i-object-position/

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать через background-size: cover; как сам фон. То есть в отличае от ответа fanfer картинка задаётся не элементом img а самим фоном.

```css
.el {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png);
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-position: center;
}

.e1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 220px;
}

.e2 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el e1"></div>
<div class="el e2"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Рассматривал этот вариант как запасной. В будущем, картинки должны будут перелистываться, а бэкграунд для этого (могу ошибаться) не очень правильно использовать.

Comment: @Дмитрий Полянин ещё немного и разменяешь три тысячи. Картинка понравилась, если не возражаешь, заберу себе для будущих примеров:)

Comment: @Alexandr_T спасибо! жду недождусь. я не автор картинки, она из интернета, тек что бери ))

Comment: @Alexandr_T Кстати я всегда когда выбираю картинки для тестов, или делаю сайт но вначале тестовый дизайн, сразу стараюсь сделать что бы было красиво, и картинки тоже сразу выбираю красивые, так приятнее работать.

Comment: @Alexandr_T это не вы поспособствовали 3000?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин  это неприличный вопрос :))))))))))) Я просто мимо проходил :)

Comment: @Alexandr_T спасибо доброму путнику! ))) У меня 3000 было целью, можно теперь показывать потенциальному работодателю в резюме )). Но почему-то за 50 или 100 до 3000 скорость уменьшилась в разы, хотя я так же старался, ощущение было что выжимать надо... вот задумываюсь о причинах.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин А тут не угадаешь никогда причины. Я давно бросил анализировать их. Некоторые ответы я пишу по два дня, обстоятельно, с примерами, даже какие-то формулы вывожу, на мой взгляд очевидная польза должна быть, а результат пшик, даже от автора вопроса, как например здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761733/28748  а некоторые на ходу ответы, сделанные за 10 минут засыпают плюсами. Так что, пиши больше ответов, как на рыбалке - будет поклевка, поймаешь, нет - не растраивайся.

Comment: @Alexandr_T спасибо за поддержку!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.img_wrap {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.d1{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.d2{
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.img_wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_wrap d1">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>

<div class="img_wrap d2">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но таки это object-fit: cover )

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo минус не обязательно было ставить)

Comment: Я его и не ставил. Зачем мне это.