# SVG рисование окружности с 4 цветами

Tags: svg, рисование

Как нарисовать окружность с 4 различными цветами?
Пробовал вот так

```html
 <svg width="200" height="200">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="26"
        stroke="black"
        stroke-opacity="1"
        stroke-dasharray="40 120"
        stroke-dashoffset="40"
        style="fill: none;
        stroke-width: 15px;" />
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="26"
        stroke="green"
        stroke-opacity="0.5"
        stroke-dasharray="40 120"
        stroke-dashoffset=""
        style="fill: none;
        stroke-width: 15px;" /></svg>
<!-- 25%  2*Math.Pi*r*0,25 = 122.46 -->  
<!-- 75%  2*Math.Pi*r*0,75 = 367.38 -->
```

Не выходит. ЧТо за ерунда?!

Comment: Лучше код размещать в сниппете. Для этого в окне редактирования нажмите CTRL+M или выберите иконку "фрагмент кода js/css/html

Comment: Спасибо, все никак не мог с этим разобраться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Окружность поделена на 6 частей

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="220" height="220" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
   
      <g fill="none" stroke-width="15" transform="translate(100,100)">
        <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,-50" stroke="green"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,50" stroke="crimson"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,100" stroke="yellow"/>
        <path d="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,50" stroke="cyan"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,-50" stroke="red"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,-100" stroke="blue"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

### С градиентами 6 частей окружности

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="220" height="220" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="redyel" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffff00"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="yelgre" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffff00"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="grecya" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ffff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="cyablu" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ffff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="blumag" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff00ff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="magred" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff00ff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>   
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    
      <g fill="none" stroke-width="15" transform="translate(100,100)">
        <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,-50" stroke="url(#redyel)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,50" stroke="url(#yelgre)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,100" stroke="url(#grecya)"/>
        <path d="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,50" stroke="url(#cyablu)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,-50" stroke="url(#blumag)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,-100" stroke="url(#magred)"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Ты как всегда в своей стихии...)))) Красиво...

Answer (score 2):

```html
   <svg width="200" height="200">
        <circle cx="52" cy="52" r="26"
        stroke="red"
        stroke-opacity="1"
        stroke-dasharray="41 122"
        style="fill: none;
        stroke-width: 52px;" />
      <circle cx="52" cy="52" r="26"
        stroke="green"
        stroke-opacity="1"
        stroke-dasharray="41 122"
              stroke-dashoffset="41"
        style="fill: none;
        stroke-width: 52px;" />
      <circle cx="52" cy="52" r="26"
        stroke="blue"
        stroke-opacity="1"
        stroke-dasharray="41 122"
              stroke-dashoffset="82"
        style="fill: none;
        stroke-width: 52px;" />
      <circle cx="52" cy="52" r="26"
        stroke="yellow"
        stroke-opacity="1"
        stroke-dasharray="41 122"
              stroke-dashoffset="123"
        style="fill: none;
        stroke-width: 52px;" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: Вот почему он с наклоном получается? И как сделать например для 6, 8 и т.д

Comment: @Анатолий разделить длину окружности на 6, 8 и т.д. l=2πR

Comment: Я разделил, и как дальше сделать?

Comment: мне никто не может помочь?

Comment: @Анатолий разделили,а дальше в stroke-dasharray указываете длину отрезка и расстояние,свойство stroke-dashoffset задает смещение.Подробнее про всей свойства тут http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-fill-and-stroke/#stroke-dashoffset

Comment: не понимаю как указать эту длину и расстояние

Comment: @Анатолий  l=2πR поделили на 4 получили 41 это отрезок,163-31=122 расстояние

Comment: ,Расстояние этого отрезка?

Comment: Да,а  stroke-dashoffset задаете смещение на величину отрезка

Comment: 41 тогда что? Ничего не могу понять

Comment: @Анатолий Вот посмотрите пост про разделение окружности на 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 и т.д с помощью `stroke-dasharray`, `stroke-dashoffset`  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761733/28748

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться