# Как сделать изогнутые прямоугольники (bent rectangle) в SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

У меня есть проект, над которым я работаю. Необходимо сделать круговую навигацию с кнопками, которые выглядят как сегменты вокруг `Iron Man`, изображенной ниже.

Я могу рисовать простые фигуры, но я затрудняюсь нарисовать эти полосы с изогнутой формой, как на рисунке ниже.

Я включил пример `clip path`, и я думаю, что `SVG` - это то, что мне нужно.

HTML

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 160%,transparent 45%,red 44.5%,red 85%,transparent 85%);
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 65% 90%, 35% 90%);
        clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 80% 0, 65% 90%, 35% 90%);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

### Дополнительные примеры сегментов

**6 сегментов**

Подставляем в скрипт, количество сегментов и

черта- `dash=0.8`  пробел - `gap = 0.2`

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 40;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .8*perimeter/6;
let gap = .2*perimeter/6;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
```

```css
circle{stroke-width:20px; stroke:purple;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110"></svg>
```

**6 сегментов**

черта- `dash=0.2` пробел - `gap = 0.8`

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 40;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .2*perimeter/6;
let gap = .8*perimeter/6;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
```

```css
circle{stroke-width:20px; stroke:yellowgreen;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110"></svg>
```

**12 сегментов**

черта- `dash=0.2`  пробел - `gap = 0.8`

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 40;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .2*perimeter/12;
let gap = .8*perimeter/12;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
```

```css
circle{stroke-width:20px; stroke:purple;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110"></svg>
```

**10 сегментов + background**

черта- `dash=0.9`  пробел - `gap = 0.1`

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 40;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .9*perimeter/10;
let gap = .1*perimeter/10;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
```

```css
circle{stroke-width:20px; stroke:greenyellow;fill:gold;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110"></svg>
```

**Шестеренка**

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 30;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .5*perimeter/20;
let gap = .5*perimeter/20;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
```

```css
circle{stroke-width:14px; stroke:gray;fill:gray;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110"> </svg>
```

**Update**

Благодарю за идею **@UModeL**

**Подсолнух**

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 30;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .7*perimeter/35;
let gap = .3*perimeter/35;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
```

```css
circle{stroke-width:22px; stroke:#FFEB3B; fill:#4d4d4d;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110"> </svg>
```

Comment: если цвета для "10-и сегментов" поменять на такие:  `stroke: #FFEB3B; fill: #4d4d4d;`, то можно назвать пример "подсолнух"))

Comment: @UModeL cсейчас добавлю :) Я хотел показать тебе, как штудировал эту тему, отвечал на вопрос, а вопрошающий даже спасибо не сказал.. Потом понял свою ошибку,- ему просто нужно было дать быстро готовый ответ, а я всю теорию на примерах дал )))) ха-ха-ха https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760290/28748

Comment: да, ребята хотят всё и сразу, а потом по десять раз переспрашивают. Самый главный плюс в том, что развёрнутый ответ с примерами, может и не помог данному человеку (в силу срочности), но поможет тысячам с таким же вопросом.

Comment: по вашей ссылке, реально огромная работа! Не знаю, хватило бы у меня терпения, для стольких примеров и разбора. Я пониже летаю - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/916526/265406 ))

Answer (score 5):

- Сначала я создаю один сегмент (path). Затем я снова использую его, с
  помощью вращения.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
const deg = 180 / Math.PI;
let R = 50;//внешний радиус
let r = 35;// внутренний радиус
let A = 2*Math.PI/7;// угол для сегмента + пробел
let a = 2*A/3; //  угол для сегмента


let path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'path');
let p1 = {x:0,y:-R}
let p2 = {
  x : R*Math.cos(a - Math.PI/2),
  y : R*Math.sin(a - Math.PI/2)
}
let p3 = {
  x : r*Math.cos(a - Math.PI/2),
  y : r*Math.sin(a - Math.PI/2)
}
let p4 = {
  x : 0,
  y : -r
}
let d = `M${p1.x},${p1.y}
         A${R},${R} 0 0,1,${p2.x},${p2.y}
         L${p3.x},${p3.y}
         A${r},${r} 0 0,0,${p4.x},${p4.y}
         L${p1.x},${p1.y}Z
`;
path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
path.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "arc");
defs.appendChild(path);




for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++){
 let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
  use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, "xlink:href", "#arc")
  use.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "gold");
  use.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `rotate(${i*A*deg})`);
  svg.appendChild(use); 
  
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110">
  
  <defs id="defs"></defs>
  
  <circle r="25" fill="gold" />
  
  
</svg>
```

- Или даже проще: на этот раз я использую stroke-dasharray, и я
  вычисляю размер для штриха и пробелов

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 40;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .7*perimeter/7;
let gap = .3*perimeter/7;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
```

```css
circle{stroke-width:20px; stroke:black;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110"></svg>
```

**Примечания:**

код можно использовать как генератор любого количества сегментов. Можно изменять также длину штриха и пробела, получая геометрически точные сегменты.

Пример с 5 сегментами:

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 40;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .8*perimeter/5;
let gap = .2*perimeter/5;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
```

```css
circle{stroke-width:20px; stroke:dodgerblue;fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox= "-100 -55 200 110"></svg>
```

**Ещё примеры**

```html
<style>
circle{stroke-width:20px; stroke:purple;fill:none;}
</style>
<svg id="svg" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox= "-100 -60 200 110">
<circle id="two" cx="0" cy="0" r="28" fill="none"  stroke-width="5" />

</svg>
<script>
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 40;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .8*perimeter/6;
let gap = .2*perimeter/6;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
</script>
```

**Вращение сегментов при наведении**

```css
circle {
stroke-width:20px;
 stroke:purple;
 fill:transparent;
 
 }
 circle:hover {
 stroke:dodgerblue;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 6s linear infinite;
  animation: rotate 6s linear infinite;
 }
 
 @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes rotate {
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox= "-100 -60 200 110">
<circle id="two" cx="0" cy="0" r="28" fill="none"  stroke-width="5" />

</svg>
<script>
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let R = 40;

let perimeter = 2*Math.PI*R
let dash = .8*perimeter/6;
let gap = .2*perimeter/6;


let dasharray = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "r", R);
dasharray.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", `${dash}, ${gap}`);

svg.appendChild(dasharray);
</script>
```

Comment: Считаю самым правильным первый вариант, ибо делается меню, где сегменты являются кнопками (читай отдельными элементами). А, в случае со `stroke-dasharray`, будет затруднительно отлавливать события для каждого штриха. Но, решения полезны в любом случае.