# Передать переменную из js в svg

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<svg  id="example2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <image id="i0" width="300" height="300" x="150" y="0" xlink:href="logo.png"  />
  <animateTransform xlink:href="#i0" attributeName="transform" type="translate" from="900 300" to="0 620" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />


</svg> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = document.body.clientWidth;
   var y = document.body.clientHeight;
 </script>
```

Есть такая вот анимация перемещения изображения. Как можно передать в параметр анимации `from` значение переменных `x, y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var x = document.body.clientWidth;
   var y = document.body.clientHeight;

   document.querySelector('svg animateTransform').setAttribute('from', x + ' ' + y);
```

Comment: А если у меня много анимаций? как к ним обратиться по id? или использовать [0]?

Comment: Можно по атрибутам `document.querySelector('svg animateTransform[attributeName="transform"]')` или `document.querySelectorAll('svg animateTransform').forEach(anim => {anim.setAttribute('from', x + ' ' + y);})` АААА если надо обратиться к одному из многих, то да `document.querySelectorAll('svg animateTransform')[index]`

Comment: @Leonid не нравится, смешно, больше не буду хвалить (((

Comment: @Leonid Всюду не успеть. Посмотрите, какой сегодня день, вопросы так и сыплются. Ответил и подробно ответил уже на много вопросов, плюс делаю анимации, которые готовлю для публикации, плюс намечен один интересный перевод на сегодня. Конечно вернусь в топик, когда захочется ответить.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, так все-таки есть особая магия при обращении с элементами дерева SVG или можно во всех браузерах работать как с обычными DOM элементами. А если вставляется через object?

Comment: @Leonid Очень много нюансов в этом вопросе. Напрямую c object через DOM работать затруднительно. Но способы есть, встречал статьи на EnSO, если интересует, поищу и переведу. Вместе с object как правило используется use и svg элементы сразу попадают в shadow DOM/ Тоже можно работать, но нюансов ещё больше Ну а в остальных случаях работа с SVG ничем не отличается от других элементов HTML

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо за информацию, буду ждать нового вопроса-ответа на эту тему. Будет интересно. Получается, что через createElement можно динамически SVG составить на странице? Мне приходилось динамически составлять SVG на сервере и отправлять клиенту в виде файла, но об этом я не думал совсем.

Comment: @Leonid только учтите, что при создании элементов SVG нужно использовать document.createElement**NS** вот для примера  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/916533/28748

Comment: Ужыыыысссс!!! Да, надо изучить вопрос... А новые методы типа append, appendTo, insertAdjacentHTML?

Comment: @Leonid насчет последнего не знаю, не встречал, а первые два точно работают