# Как с помощью SVG нарисовать штрихи и сектора по кругу?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Имеется круг. К его окружности необходимо добавить градусную меру - маленькие штрихи по 1 градусу и среднего размера штрихи по 10 градусов.

В svg и d3 не сильно силен, так что, если не сложно - дополните мой [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/oLq9jp37/2/).

Получилось сделать что-то подобное, визуально вроде бы и кажется, что видна разметка, но решение все равно не верное.

```
<path d="M 429.9,375 
        C 471.3,303.3 446.7,211.5 375,170.1 
        C 303.3,128.7 211.5,153.3 170.1,225 
        C 128.7,296.7 153.3,388.5 225,429.9 
        C 296.7,471.3 388.5,446.7 429.9,375 z " 
        stroke-dasharray="1,3"              
        stroke-width="8"
      />
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот версия на d3:

```js
d3.select("svg")
   .selectAll("path.tick")
   .data(d3.range(360))
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .classed("tick", true)
   .attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("d", d => {
      let s = d % 10 ? 10 : 20;
      d = d / 180 * Math.PI;
      let x = Math.cos(d);
      let y = Math.sin(d);
      let r = 200;
      return `M ${x*r}     , ${y*r} 
              L ${x*(r-s)} , ${y*(r-s)}`;
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="-250 -250 500 500"></svg>
```

p.s.: а что с вашим примером делать надо я не понял

Comment: Грубо говоря - интегрировать ваш код в уже мой имеющийся. Но вы мне и так очень помогли. Спасибо большое

Comment: @VladislavStarikov попозже сделаю, если у Вас не получится

Answer (score 4):

Штрихи и сектора реализуются с помощью команды `stroke=dasharray`

Более подробно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760290/28748)

**Расчет для 12 секторов**

при радиусе `R=200` Длина окружности равна -  `2 * PI * R = 1256.16`

Длина одного сектора - `1256 / 12 = 104.72`

Формула `stroke-dasharray="102 2.72"`  длина черты - `102`, длина пробела - `2.72` в сумме длина одного сектора - `104.72`

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
 
   <!-- Внешний круг -->
 <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="261" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="2"  /> 
  <!--  круг c 12 секторами-->
 <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="200" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="100" stroke-dasharray="102 2.72" />
  <!--  круг c 150 секторами Это штрихи-->
 <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="255" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="12" stroke-dasharray="3.14 3.14" /> 
  <!--  Внутренний круг -->
 <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="150" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="2"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: @Vladislav Starikov посмотрите этот ответ.  Это решение вам будет легче всего встроить в ваше приложение. На мой взгляд лучше понять как это работает вручную, а уж потом, разобравшись, подключать мощные библиотеки.

Comment: Я уже интегрировал решение @stranger-in-the-q но ваше я тоже попробую, чтобы уже полностью разобраться в вопросе

Comment: @Vladislav Starikov ловите плюс за интересный вопрос

Comment: @Alexandr_TT только ничего мощного тут нет, автор попросил на d3 и я исполнил на нем, на обычном js листинг бы не сильно вырос

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  а вы отрицаете, что `d3` мощная библиотека? Я не против `d3`, она мне очень нравится, я просто хотел донести до автора вопроса, что прежде чем использовать библиотеки, нужно хоть немного попытаться разобраться в SVG.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT d3 очень мощная, но конкретно в этом примере нет ничего из её мощи, только d3-selection, это очень маленькая её часть, исключительно для DOM манипуляций

Comment: для сравнения добавил js версию, она даже короче =) но это только потому, что очень простой пример, обычно d3 сильно в выигрыше по длине листинга

Comment: плюс Вам за Ваши старания

Answer (score 3):

Версия на чистом js, формируем один svg path

```js
let d = ''
for (let i=0; i<360; i++) {
    let r = 200;
    let s = r - (i % 10 ? 10 : 50);
    let a = i / 180 * Math.PI;
    let x = Math.cos(a);
    let y = Math.sin(a);
    d += `
      M ${x*r} , ${y*r} 
      L ${x*s} , ${y*s}
    `;
}

document.querySelector("svg path")
        .setAttribute('d', d);
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-250 -250 500 500">
  <circle r='200' stroke='black' fill='none'/>
  <circle r='190' stroke='black' fill='none'/>
  <circle r='150' stroke='black' fill='none'/>
  <path stroke='black' />
</svg>
```

Comment: так не циферблат ему было надо, а как в его [примере сделано](https://jsfiddle.net/oLq9jp37/2/)  с секторами

Comment: А что означает знак вопроса в коде ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский это тернарная условная операция, короткая запись if-esle

Comment: Спасибо не знал..

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский есть во многих языках программироания https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Плюсик от меня..

Comment: @Alexandr_TT добавил 3 circle=)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я вижу, плюсану тебе сейчас, но это называется забивать микроскопом гвозди :) Вот смотри, у меня всего четыре строчки svg и всё! И у тебя 4 строчки svg + 14 строчек `JS` Я пытаюсь донести до новичков, учите SVG, потом уже хватайтесь за библиотеки :))))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT решение c dasharray протекает, посмотрите внимательно на места соединений штрихов от разных кругов, и Вы просто посчитали на калькуляторе значения, а так бы тоже был js =)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  это  причина не `dasharray`  а полупиксельное перекрытие. Не понятно зачем я выставил `stroke-width="1.5"`