# Как добавить многоцветную строку в стиле Google One к круглому изображению?

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я создаю веб-сайт для клуба `Google DSC` в моем университете, и я хотел бы добавить границу стиля [Google One style border](https://ssl.gstatic.com/subscriptions/img/avatar_2_c4f462f663ba453cb33240e1c5da0506.png) к круговым изображениям портфолио на сайте.

Мне интересует, как сделать это с помощью CSS, но также подойдут предварительно отрисованные решения в `Photoshop` или `Illustrator`.

Я попытался изменить код, приведенный [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162635/10839571), но не смог добиться идеального эффекта.

```css
.test {
  margin: 25px 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  background-size: 100% 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), 
                    linear-gradient(30deg, #ea4335 36%, #4285f4 30%),
                    linear-gradient(120deg, #4285f4 36%, #34a853 30%),
                    linear-gradient(300deg, #fbbc04 36%, #ea4335 30%),
                    linear-gradient(210deg, #34a853 36%, #fbbc04 30%);
  background-position: center center, left top, right top, left bottom, right bottom;
  background-origin: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Как видите, цвета границ выровнены неправильно.

Есть ли способ сделать это, используя более простой метод?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56839310/7394871

Comment: Саша Ты здесь?  Помощь нужна ..мелкая

Comment: @MaximLensky :жду в чате

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю решение без особых вычислений:

```html
<svg viewbox="-5 -5 10 10" height="90vh">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask1">
      <circle r="4.5" stroke="white" fill="black" stroke-width="0.5"></circle> 
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask2">
      <circle r="4"fill="white"></circle> 
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#mask1)" transform="rotate(-45)">
    <rect width="7" height="7" fill="#fabb04" x="-7" y="-6"></rect>
    <rect width="7" height="7" fill="#34a852" x="-5" y="-1"></rect>
    <rect width="7" height="7" fill="#ea4335" x="-2" y="-5"></rect>
    <rect width="7" height="7" fill="#4285f4" x="0"  y="-1"></rect>
  </g>
  <image x="-4" y="-4" width="8" height="8" mask="url(#mask2)"
    xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q67w.gif"></image>
  <style>
    svg>g {
      transition: 1s;
    }
    svg:hover>g {
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

  </style>
</svg>
```

Или так:

```html
<svg viewbox="-5 -5 10 10" height="90vh">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask1">
      <circle r="4.5" stroke="white" fill="black" stroke-width="0.5"></circle> 
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask2">
      <circle r="4"fill="white"></circle> 
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#mask1)" transform="rotate(-45)">
    <g transform="translate(-11,-12)">
      <rect width="20" height="10" fill="#ea4335"></rect>
      <rect width="10" height="10" fill="#fabb04"></rect>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-11,-2)">
      <rect width="20" height="10" fill="#4285f4"></rect>
      <rect width="10" height="10" fill="#34a852"></rect>
    </g>
  </g>
  <image x="-4" y="-4" width="8" height="8" mask="url(#mask2)"
    xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q67w.gif"></image>
  <style>
    svg rect, svg #mask1>circle {
      transition: 1s;
    }
    svg:hover rect {
      transform: translate(2px, 4px);
    }
    svg:hover #mask1 > circle {
      stroke-width: 0.7;
    }
  </style>
</svg>
```

Comment: Свежее решение, интересный подход. Было бы ещё полезней, по крайней мере для меня, увидеть реализацию анимации вращения строки при наведении.

Comment: Понял, задумал пару анимаций, доделаю попозже

Comment: я имел ввиду это, конкретное решение с прямоугольниками. Понятно, что анимацию, вращения строки на JS сделать не проблема, таких решений я видел достаточно много. Интересует именно решение анимации с прямоугольниками, обрезанное круговой маской.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я про них самых, сделал

Comment: не то к сожалению Ты двигаешь прямоугольники, поэтому происходит визуальное изменение строки с изменением размеров цветных секторов. А я спросил именно вращение, с сохранением размеров цветных секторов. Смотри, мой пример анимации

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я сделал 2 и в обоих увеличивается толщина кольца, в одной есть вращение

Comment: @ Stranger in the Q ну как вариант анимации конечно имеет право быть. Но это не то. Если ты меня понимаешь и посмотрел мой пример, то ....   Зачем спорить, можешь сделать, - сделай. Плюс я тебе и так поставил, сейчас добавлю галочку

Comment: @Alexandr_TT чесслово не понимаю в чем принципиальное отличие, поворачивается и поворачивается, разве что поворот не на 720 градусов а на 180

Comment: сектора не поворачиваются, а меняют свою длину. Это просто трюк - двигать прямоугольники и обрезать маской :-) Фактически вращения нет. **Я  просил вращение без изменения длины секторов**

Comment: @Alexandr_TT посмотри еще раз первый сниппет - там `transform:rotate()`

Comment: Да уже огонь!!!

Comment: @Stranger in the Q посмотрел, вижу, что изменил сейчас.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT поворот там был самого первого варианта, когда я добавил анимацию, по твоей просьбе убрал изменение толщины, но поворот был изначально (см историю правок)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q поворот появился в 4 правке 31 мин. назад. О чём мы спорим? .. :-)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT и эта первая версия с анимациями

Answer (score 3):

### Вариант SVG

Для более глубокого изучения и понимания этого ответа можно почитать топик на нашем сайте:

[Помогите с dasharray и dashoffset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760290/28748)

Для создания разноцветных секторов окружности используем атрибут `stroke-dasharray`

**Расчет длин черточек и пробелов:**

- Для радиуса `R=100px` `длина окружности =`2 * 3.1415 * 100 = 628.3
  px`
- Чтобы получить черту равной одной четвертой окружности  расcчитаем
  атрибуты `stroke-dasharray`:  `628.3 / 4 = 157.075`
  Пробел    составит 3 / 4 длины окружности = `471px`

Итого параметы атрибута будут равны   `stroke-dasharray="157 471"`

Но так как длина синего , красного и зеленого секторов немного больше четверти окружности, то добавляем эту разницу.   `stroke-dasharray="183.255 445.045"`

- `stroke-dashoffset="78.54"` сдвигает начало сектора на 1/8 длины
  окружности

Пример кода для одного сектора:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" > 
   
<circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="8" />   
    
<circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.255 445.045" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 
 
 </svg>
```

- И  таким же способом устанавливаем  параметры аттрибута
  `stroke-dasharray` для остальных цветных секторов.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >  
   
<circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.255 445.045" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 
  <circle id="red" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#EA4335" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="203.255 425.045" stroke-dashoffset="281.9" /> 
  <circle id="gold" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#FABB04" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="78.54 549.76" stroke-dashoffset="340 " /> 
   <circle id="green" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#34A852" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.255 445.045" stroke-dashoffset="525.225 " /> 
 </svg>
```

- Добавляем изображение и вырезаем его с помощью маски по размеру
  окружностей:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="40%" height="40%" viewBox="0 0 250 250" >  

 <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="20" stroke="black"  />
  </mask>
</defs>

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGg5.jpg" x="0" y="23" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
 <circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 
  <circle id="red" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#EA4335" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="203.3 425.1" stroke-dashoffset="281.9" /> 
  <circle id="gold" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#FABB04" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="80 549.7" stroke-dashoffset="345 " /> 
    <circle id="green" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#34A852" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="525.2 " /> 
 
 </svg>
```

**Решение адаптивно и работает одинаково во всех современных браузерах в включая `IE11`,`Edge`**

### SVG+CSS анимация

Чтобы оживить приложение, я добавляю опции анимации.

**#1. Анимация вращения строки вокруг изображения**

- Оберните все круги, которые образуют многоцветную линию,  групповым
  тегом `<g>`
- `fill ="none"` заменяется на `fill ="transparent"` для срабатывания
  анимации при наведении на любую часть окружности

```css
.student {
background: rgb(238,174,202);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(148,208,233,1) 100%);
}
.container {
display: inline-block;
width:25%;
}
#gr1 {
transform-origin:125px 125px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#gr1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
          transform: rotate(720deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="student"> 
 <div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 250 250" >  

 <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="20" stroke="black"  />
  </mask>
</defs>

 <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzNqO.jpg" x="0" y="24" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 

<g id="gr1"> 
<circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="transparent" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 

  <circle id="red" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#EA4335" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="203.3 425.1" stroke-dashoffset="281.9" /> 

  <circle id="gold" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#FABB04" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="80 549.7" stroke-dashoffset="345 " /> 
 
   <circle id="green" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#34A852" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="525.2 " /> 
 </g>
 </svg> 
</div>  
 
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 250 250" >  

 <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="20" stroke="black"  />
  </mask>
</defs>

 <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4AlZ.jpg" x="0" y="25" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
<g id="gr1">   
<circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="transparent" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 

  <circle id="red" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#EA4335" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="203.3 425.1" stroke-dashoffset="281.9" /> 

  <circle id="gold" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#FABB04" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="80 549.7" stroke-dashoffset="345 " /> 
 
   <circle id="green" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#34A852" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="525.2 " /> 
</g> 
 </svg>  
 </div> 
 <div class="container">
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 250 250" >  

 <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="20" stroke="black"  />
  </mask>
</defs>

 <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG6VN.png" x="0" y="25" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
<g id="gr1">  
<circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="transparent" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 

  <circle id="red" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#EA4335" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="203.3 425.1" stroke-dashoffset="281.9" /> 

  <circle id="gold" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#FABB04" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="80 549.7" stroke-dashoffset="345 " /> 
 
   <circle id="green" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#34A852" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="525.2 " /> 
</g> 
   </svg>  
  </div> 
 </div>
```

**2.# Анимация вращения изображения внутри многоцветной строки**

Используемые правила CSS:

```
#img {
transform-origin:125px 125px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```css
.student {

background: rgb(238,174,202);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(148,208,233,1) 100%);
}
.container {
display: inline-block;
width:25%;
}
#img {
transform-origin:125px 125px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="student"> 
 <div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 250 250" >  

 <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="20" stroke="black"  />
  </mask>
</defs>

 <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzNqO.jpg" x="0" y="24" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
   
<circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 

  <circle id="red" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#EA4335" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="203.3 425.1" stroke-dashoffset="281.9" /> 

  <circle id="gold" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#FABB04" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="80 549.7" stroke-dashoffset="345 " /> 
 
   <circle id="green" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#34A852" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="525.2 " /> 
 
 </svg> 
</div>  
 
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 250 250" >  

 <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="20" stroke="black"  />
  </mask>
</defs>

 <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4AlZ.jpg" x="0" y="25" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
   
<circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 

  <circle id="red" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#EA4335" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="203.3 425.1" stroke-dashoffset="281.9" /> 

  <circle id="gold" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#FABB04" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="80 549.7" stroke-dashoffset="345 " /> 
 
   <circle id="green" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#34A852" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="525.2 " /> 
 
 </svg>  
 </div> 
 <div class="container">
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 250 250" >  

 <defs> 
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="20" stroke="black"  />
  </mask>
</defs>

 <image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG6VN.png" x="0" y="25" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" /> 
   
<circle id="blue" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#4285F4" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="78.54" /> 

  <circle id="red" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#EA4335" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="203.3 425.1" stroke-dashoffset="281.9" /> 

  <circle id="gold" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#FABB04" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="80 549.7" stroke-dashoffset="345 " /> 
 
   <circle id="green" cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#34A852" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="183.2 445.1" stroke-dashoffset="525.2 " /> 
 
   </svg>  
  </div> 
 </div>
```