# Как в завиcимости от того на сколько проскролили страницу менять значение stroke-dashoffset?

Tags: javascript, svg

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  const scrollCount = window.pageYOffset;
   const bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
  console.log(scrollCount, bodyHeight)
})
```

```css
.prgoress_scrollup {
  position: fixed;
    right: 80px;
    bottom: 40px;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 119, 249, 0.2);
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all 200ms linear !important;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

.prgoress_scrollup svg.progress-circle path {
    stroke: #ff7426;
    stroke-width: 4;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 200ms linear !important;
}
.prgoress_scrollup svg path {
    fill: none;
}


p {
  color: #fff;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="prgoress_scrollup active-progress">
        <svg class="progress-circle svg-content" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-1 -1 102 102">
            <path d="M50,1 a49,49 0 0,1 0,98 a49,49 0 0,1 0,-98" 
              
            style="transition: stroke-dashoffset 10ms linear 0s; 
              
            stroke-dasharray: 307.919, 307.919; 
              
            stroke-dashoffset: 48.0429;"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
  <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
  
  p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
  
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
  
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
  
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
  
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
  <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
<p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
    <p>Lorem  fugiat, explicabo veritatis sit ue eligendi sunt, perspiciatis.</p>
```

Comment: Взгляните сюда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760290/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-dasharray-%D0%B8-dashoffset?ysclid=lkkuwtv18t742283314