# Как нарисовать автомобиль с помощью команд SVG

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Ниже изображение автомобиля в формате PNG.
 Я хочу сделать анимацию движения автомобиля вдоль какой-нибудь траектории. Желательно, чтобы колёса автомобиля вращались. Я понимаю, что для этого необходимо перевести картинку в формат SVG.

Как это сделать?

С помощью векторного редактора или вручную, используя формулы SVG, или, как-то по другому, например, применяя трансформации CSS3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Движение автобуса по заданной траектории:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

line {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: #bf0208;
}
```

```html
<svg width="550" height="149" viewBox="0 0 550 149" style="background-color: #000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <filter id="blur-filter-light" x="-1" y="-1" width="10" height="10">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="18" />
    </filter>
    <g transform="scale(0.90) translate(0 -120)" id="myCar">
      <rect x="50" y="40" width="210" height="35" fill="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)" stroke-width="5" stroke="#bf0208" rx="3" />
      <g>
        <rect x="50" y="70" width="210" height="35" fill="#bf0208" stroke-width="5" stroke="#bf0208" rx="3" />
        <rect x="259" y="70" width="5" height="15" fill="yellow" rx="5" />
        <polygon points="450,90 267,80 450,60" fill="yellow" filter="url(#blur-filter-light)" />
        <text x="125" y="82" fill="white" font-size="1.2em" font-family="Monospace">Lorem Bus</text>
      </g>
      <g>
        <line x1="80" x2="80" y1="40" y2="70" />
        <line x1="110" x2="110" y1="40" y2="70" />
        <line x1="140" x2="140" y1="40" y2="70" />
        <line x1="170" x2="170" y1="40" y2="70" />
        <line x1="200" x2="200" y1="40" y2="70" />
        <line x1="230" x2="230" y1="40" y2="70" />
      </g>
      <g>
        <circle cx="75" cy="105" r="15" fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
        <rect width="10" height="4" x="70" y="104" rx="3" fill="white" />
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 75 105;360 75 105" dur="1s" repeatCount="7" />
      </g>
      <g>
        <circle cx="110" cy="105" r="15" fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
        <rect width="10" height="4" x="105" y="104" rx="3" fill="white" />
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 110 105;360 110 105" dur="1s" repeatCount="7" />
      </g>
      <g>
        <circle cx="225" cy="105" r="15" fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
        <rect width="10" height="4" x="220" y="104" rx="3" fill="white" />
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 225 105;360 225 105" dur="1s" repeatCount="7" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <path id="carPath" style="fill:none; stroke:white; stroke-width:1px;" d="m 0,147.8636 612.74654,0.53454" />
    <animateMotion xlink:href="#myCar" begin="0.3s" dur="7s" repeatCount="none">
      <mpath xlink:href="#carPath" />
    </animateMotion>
    <svg width="550" height="149" viewBox="0 0 550 149" style="border: 1px solid; background-color: #000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <filter id="blur-filter-light" x="-1" y="-1" width="10" height="10">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="18" />
      </filter>
      <g transform="scale(0.90) translate(0 -120)" id="myCar">
        <rect x="50" y="40" width="210" height="35" fill="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)" stroke-width="5" stroke="#bf0208" rx="3" />
        <g>
          <rect x="50" y="70" width="210" height="35" fill="#bf0208" stroke-width="5" stroke="#bf0208" rx="3" />
          <rect x="259" y="70" width="5" height="15" fill="yellow" rx="5" />
          <polygon points="450,90 267,80 450,60" fill="yellow" filter="url(#blur-filter-light)" />
          <text x="125" y="82" fill="white" font-size="1.2em" font-family="Monospace">Lorem Bus</text>
        </g>
        <g>
          <line x1="80" x2="80" y1="40" y2="70" />
          <line x1="110" x2="110" y1="40" y2="70" />
          <line x1="140" x2="140" y1="40" y2="70" />
          <line x1="170" x2="170" y1="40" y2="70" />
          <line x1="200" x2="200" y1="40" y2="70" />
          <line x1="230" x2="230" y1="40" y2="70" />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="75" cy="105" r="15" fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
          <rect width="12" height="4" x="70" y="104" rx="3" fill="white" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 75 105;360 75 105" dur="1s" repeatCount="7" />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="110" cy="105" r="15" fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
          <rect width="12" height="4" x="105" y="104" rx="3" fill="white" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 110 105;360 110 105" dur="1s" repeatCount="7" />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="225" cy="105" r="15" fill="gray" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
          <rect width="12" height="4" x="220" y="104" rx="3" fill="white" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 225 105;360 225 105" dur="1s" repeatCount="7" />
        </g>
      </g>
      <path id="carPath" style="fill:none; stroke:white; stroke-width:1px;" d="m 0,147.8636 612.74654,0.53454" />
      <animateMotion xlink:href="#myCar" begin="0.3s" dur="7s" repeatCount="none">
        <mpath xlink:href="#carPath" />
      </animateMotion>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Красиво......)))

Comment: @Air, первая работа... Lorem(London) Bus:)

Comment: работает в Лисе .. + от меня

Comment: @Arthur а в чём рисовал ?в какой проге ?

Comment: @Arthur давай в чат

Answer (score 25):

### Анимация движения автомобиля по заданной траектории

Cначала нам нужно нарисовать траекторию. Для этого открываем в векторном редакторе файл `svg` автомобиля

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Рисуем путь
- Сохраняем файл
- Чтобы убрать из файла SVG лишнюю информацию, которую сохраняет
  векторный редактор необходимо оптимизировать файл с помощью любого
  оптимизатора, например - [SVGOMG](https://svgomg.net/)
- Копируем из файла  `Path` траектории

Для анимации движения вдоль заданного пути используем команду:

`<animateMotion xlink:href="#car-dodger"  begin="0s" dur="12s" rotate="auto"    repeatCount="1"  fill="freeze" >  <mpath xlink:href="#carPath" /> </animateMotion>`   ,где

`#car-dodger"`  -  уникальный идентификатор автомобиля

`#carPath"`  - идентификатор пути, по которому движется автомобиль

*Внизу полный код:*

```html
<svg width="580" height="400" viewBox="0 0 580 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<defs>


</defs> 

<g id="car-dodger" transform="scale(0.25) translate(0 -180)">
    <!-- Top -->
      <rect x="70" y="10" width="220" height="130" fill="transparent" rx="150" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" />
    <!-- Tail Lights red -->
    <circle r="10px" fill="crimson" cx="15" cy="90" />
    
    <!-- Body -->
      <rect x="10" y="70" width="340" height="80" fill="dodgerblue" rx="30" />
      
    <g>
    <!-- Left line -->
      <line x1="145" y1="10" x2="145" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>

    <!-- Right line -->
      <line x1="215" y1="10" x2="215" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
  
    <g>
    <!-- Left bumper -->
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    
    <!-- Right bumper -->
      <rect x="325" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    </g>  
  
    <!-- Left wheel  -->
    <g stroke-dasharray="6.28 6.28">
      <circle r="40px" fill="#222" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" cx="90" cy="140"/>    
      <circle r="22px" fill="#5C5C5C" cx="90" cy="140"/> 
       <polyline points="90,140 97.5 147.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 90 140;360 90 140"  dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </g>
  
    <!-- Right wheel -->
    <g stroke-dasharray="6.28 6.28">
      <circle r="40px" fill="#222" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" cx="270" cy="140"/>
      <circle r="22px" fill="#5C5C5C" cx="270" cy="140"/> 
      <polyline points="270,140 277.5 147.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" />
      <animateTransform 
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      values="0 270 140;360 270 140"
      dur="2s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </g>  

    <g>
    <!-- Gold light -->
      <circle r="15px" fill="gold" cx="340" cy="90"/>
      
       </g>  
    </g>
 <path id="carPath"
     style="fill:none;stroke:grey;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;"
     d="m 7.00611,78.668024 c 135.65342,-0.380598 152.27447,-3.422932 228.39919,-5.604887 28.49512,-0.816753 57.35177,-7.465997 85.47454,-2.802445 80.78801,13.39694 153.5049,57.123848 229.8004,86.875768 23.91885,9.32731 71.46232,28.72505 71.46232,28.72505" /> 
    <animateMotion
     xlink:href="#car-dodger"
     begin="0s"
     dur="12s"
     rotate="auto"
     repeatCount="1"
     fill="freeze" > 
            <mpath xlink:href="#carPath" />
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 19):

Это учебный пример. Шаг за шагом будут прорисовываться детали автомобиля и по мере продвижения легко будет понять, как применяются на практике основные команды svg: `line`, `rect`, `circle`, `path`

Код svg автомобиля был взят с [сайта](http://css.yoksel.ru/)  Юлии Бухваловой (Yulya Buhvalova)

- Рисуем контур крыши и кузова автомобиля,- всего одна команда `<rect>`

```html
<svg width="580" height="200" viewBox="0 0 580 200"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<g id="car-dodger" transform="scale(1.0)">
    <!-- Top -->
      <rect x="70" y="10" width="220" height="130" fill="transparent" rx="150" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" />
 </g>  
</svg>
```

- Рисуем основную часть кузова:

```html
<svg width="580" height="200" viewBox="0 0 580 200"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
 

<g id="car-dodger" transform="scale(1.0)">
    <!-- Top -->
      <rect x="70" y="10" width="220" height="130" fill="transparent" rx="150" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" />
     <!-- Body -->
      <rect x="10" y="70" width="340" height="80" fill="dodgerblue" rx="30" />
</g>  
</svg>
```

- Добавляем оконные стойки

```html
<svg width="580" height="200" viewBox="0 0 580 200"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
 

<g id="car-dodger" transform="scale(1.0)">
    <!-- Top -->
      <rect x="70" y="10" width="220" height="130" fill="transparent" rx="150" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" />
     <!-- Body -->
      <rect x="10" y="70" width="340" height="80" fill="dodgerblue" rx="30" /> 
   
    <g>
    <!-- Left line -->
      <line x1="145" y1="10" x2="145" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>

    <!-- Right line -->
      <line x1="215" y1="10" x2="215" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
</g>  
</svg>
```

- Добавляем передний и задний бампер:

```html
<svg width="580" height="200" viewBox="0 0 580 200"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
 

<g id="car-dodger" transform="scale(1.0)">
    <!-- Top -->
      <rect x="70" y="10" width="220" height="130" fill="transparent" rx="150" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" />
     <!-- Body -->
      <rect x="10" y="70" width="340" height="80" fill="dodgerblue" rx="30" /> 
   
    <g>
    <!-- Left line -->
      <line x1="145" y1="10" x2="145" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>

    <!-- Right line -->
      <line x1="215" y1="10" x2="215" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
  <g>
    <!-- Left bumper -->
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    
    <!-- Right bumper -->
      <rect x="325" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    </g>  
</g>  
</svg>
```

- Добавляем колёса:

```html
<svg width="580" height="200" viewBox="0 0 580 200"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
<g id="car-dodger" transform="scale(1.1)">
    <!-- Top -->
      <rect x="70" y="10" width="220" height="130" fill="transparent" rx="150" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" />
   
 
    <!-- Body -->
      <rect x="10" y="70" width="340" height="80" fill="dodgerblue" rx="30" />
      
    <g>
    <!-- Left line -->
      <line x1="145" y1="10" x2="145" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>

    <!-- Right line -->
      <line x1="215" y1="10" x2="215" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
  
    <g>
    <!-- Left bumper -->
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    
    <!-- Right bumper -->
      <rect x="325" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    </g>  
  
    <!-- Left wheel  -->
    <g>
      <circle r="40px" fill="#222" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" cx="90" cy="140"/>    
      <circle r="15px" fill="#555" cx="90" cy="140"/>
    
 </g>
  
    <!-- Right wheel -->
    <g>
      <circle r="40px" fill="#222" stroke="white" stroke-width="7" cx="270" cy="140"/>
      <circle r="15px" fill="#555" cx="270" cy="140"/>
    </g>  

    
 </g>
</svg>
```

- Добавляем фары:

```html
<svg width="580" height="200" viewBox="0 0 580 200"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
 

<g id="car-dodger" transform="scale(1.0)">
    <!-- Top -->
      <rect x="70" y="10" width="220" height="130" fill="transparent" rx="150" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" />
    <!-- Tail Lights red -->
 <circle r="10px" fill="crimson" cx="15" cy="90" />
 
     <!-- Body -->
      <rect x="10" y="70" width="340" height="80" fill="dodgerblue" rx="30" /> 
   
    <g>
    <!-- Left line -->
      <line x1="145" y1="10" x2="145" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>

    <!-- Right line -->
      <line x1="215" y1="10" x2="215" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
  <g>
    <!-- Left bumper -->
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    
    <!-- Right bumper -->
      <rect x="325" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    </g>  
 
  <!-- Left wheel -->
    <g>
      <circle r="40px" fill="#222" stroke="white" stroke-width="7" cx="90" cy="140"/>    
      <circle r="15px" fill="#555" cx="90" cy="140"/>
    </g>
  
    <!-- Right wheel -->
    <g>
      <circle r="40px" fill="#222" stroke="white" stroke-width="7" cx="270" cy="140"/>
      <circle r="15px" fill="#555" cx="270" cy="140"/>
    </g>  
       <g>
    <!-- Gold light -->
      <circle r="15px" fill="gold" cx="340" cy="90"/>
      
       </g>  
</g>  
</svg>
```

Автомобиль готов. Конечно можно продолжать дальше,- украшать, добавлять новые детали, но в принципе достаточно, потому-что в анимации будет использоваться малый размер автомобиля и деталей особо не будет видно.
А вот шины лысые, добавим протектор с помощью `stroke-dasharray`  и добавим вращение колёс:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 90 140;360 90 140"  dur="2s" repeatCount="3" />
```

```html
<svg width="580" height="200" viewBox="0 0 580 200"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >


<g id="car-dodger" transform="scale(1)">
    <!-- Top -->
      <rect x="70" y="10" width="220" height="130" fill="transparent" rx="150" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" />
    <!-- Tail Lights red -->
 <circle r="10px" fill="crimson" cx="15" cy="90" />
 
    <!-- Body -->
      <rect x="10" y="70" width="340" height="80" fill="dodgerblue" rx="30" />
      
    <g>
    <!-- Left line -->
      <line x1="145" y1="10" x2="145" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>

    <!-- Right line -->
      <line x1="215" y1="10" x2="215" y2="80" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10"/>
    </g>
  
    <g>
    <!-- Left bumper -->
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    
    <!-- Right bumper -->
      <rect x="325" y="110" width="40" height="20" fill="#999" rx="10" />
    </g>  
  
    <!-- Left wheel  -->
    <g stroke-dasharray="6.28 6.28">
      <circle r="40px" fill="#222" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" cx="90" cy="140"/>    
      <circle r="22px" fill="#5C5C5C" cx="90" cy="140"/> 
    <polyline points="90,140 97.5 147.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" /> 
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform" 
       type="rotate"
       values="0 90 140;360 90 140"
       dur="2s" repeatCount="3" />
     </g>
     <!-- Right wheel -->
    <g stroke-dasharray="6.28 6.28">
      <circle r="40px" fill="#222" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" cx="270" cy="140"/>
      <circle r="22px" fill="#5C5C5C" cx="270" cy="140"/> 
   <polyline points="270,140 277.5 147.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       values="0 270 140;360 270 140"
       dur="2s" repeatCount="3" />
   </g>  

    <g>
    <!-- Gold light -->
      <circle r="15px" fill="gold" cx="340" cy="90"/>
      
       </g>  
 </g>
</svg>
```

Связанный вопрос: [Движение поезда с помощью SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/788891/28748)

Comment: Александр ты как всегда безупречен ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Спасибо Максим Это всего лишь учебный пример, делал по предложению ребят, которые очень хотят научиться SVG Заглядывай к нам на огонёк в чатик https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat бывает весело

Answer (score 12):

Пример на css

```css
*,
:before,
:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.car {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
}

.car__inner {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  animation: goToCar 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes goToCar {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.car__contour {
  height: 130px;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 25px auto -70px auto;
  border: 10px solid #1E90FF;
  border-radius: 220px / 130px;
  position: relative;
}

.car__contour:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  border: 10px solid #1E90FF;
  border-top: none;
}

.car__body {
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #1E90FF;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.car__headlight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -5px;
  background: #DC143C;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.car__headlight--front {
  top: 5px;
  left: auto;
  right: -10px;
  background: #FFD700;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.car__bumper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: -5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.car__bumper--front {
  left: auto;
  right: -20px;
}

.car__wheel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.car__wheel:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -38px 0 0 -38px;
  animation: rotateWheel 2s linear infinite;
  border: 2px dashed #fff;
}

@keyframes rotateWheel {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.car__wheel:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px
}

.car__wheel--front {
  left: auto;
  right: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="car__inner">
    <div class="car__contour"></div>
    <div class="car__body">
      <div class="car__headlight"></div>
      <div class="car__headlight car__headlight--front"></div>

      <div class="car__bumper"></div>
      <div class="car__bumper car__bumper--front"></div>

      <div class="car__wheel"></div>
      <div class="car__wheel car__wheel--front"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: классно и так быстро сделал - всего за 40 минут! Настоящий мастер CSS.  Жаль, что на css невозможно сделать движение по гладкой, криволинейной траектории

Comment: крассавчик ... 100% хардкор