# Движение поезда с помощью SVG

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

У меня есть картинка, на которой изображено движение поезда по рельсам.
Для создания анимации движения хочу использовать `SVG`.
 При всём этом у паровоза из дымовой трубы выходит дым.
 Как сделать подобную анимацию, используя `SVG`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Поэтапно сделаем каждую деталь поезда. 
В основном будут использованы такие основные команды: `path`, `rect`, `circle`, `line`.

- Изначально создадим паровоз:

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #A82F2F;
  stroke: #9F9F9F;
}

.st1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  fill: #5B5B5B;
  stroke: #842323;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #D34040;
  stroke: #9F9F9F;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}

.st3 {
  fill: #932727;
}

.st4 {
  fill: #D34040;
}

.st5 {
  fill: #5B4343;
}

.first-tr-str0 {
  fill: #DDCCCC;
  stroke: #EAE5E5;
}
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 350 350" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<path class="st0" d="M272.8,277.5h-56.2v-72.9c0-9.7,7.9-17.6,17.6-17.6h21c9.7,0,17.6,7.9,17.6,17.6V277.5z" />
<line class="st1" x1="258.5" y1="187.5" x2="258.5" y2="275.5" />
<line class="st1" x1="231.5" y1="188" x2="231.5" y2="276" />
<rect x="200.6" y="275.9" class="st2" width="88" height="66" />
<path class="st3" d="M252.5,275.5h-16V196c0-1.6,1.3-3,3-3h10.1c1.6,0,3,1.3,3,3V275.5z" />
<circle class="st4" cx="244.5" cy="210.5" r="7.5" />
<circle class="st5" cx="244.5" cy="210.5" r="4.5" />
<rect width="5" height="20" x="212" y="210" />
<rect width="5" height="20" x="212" y="250" />
<rect width="5" height="20" x="272" y="210" />
<rect width="5" height="20" x="272" y="250" />
</svg>
```

- Создаём оставшиеся прицепы поезда:

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<g>
  <rect width="10" height="9" x="240" y="40" />
  <rect width="90" height="150" x="200" y="49" fill="gray" rx="5" />
</g>
<g>
  <rect width="10" height="9" x="240" y="199" />
  <rect width="90" height="150" x="200" y="208" fill="gray" rx="5" />
</g>
</svg>
```

- Сделаем рельсы от начала до конца `ViewBox`:

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<defs>
  <rect id="rect" width="95" height="20" fill="#663300" />
</defs>
<g>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="10"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="50"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="90"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="130"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="170"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="210"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="250"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="290"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="330"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="370"/>
</g>
<g>
  <line x1="230" y1="400" x2="230" y2="0" stroke="#232b2b" stroke-width="5" />
  <line x1="165" y1="400" x2="165" y2="0" stroke="#232b2b" stroke-width="5" />
</g>
</svg>
```

- Теперь мы должны сделать анимацию дыма, выходящего из трубы паровоза:

  > Будем использовать `filter` & `animateTransform`

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #A82F2F;
  stroke: #9F9F9F;
}

.st1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  fill: #5B5B5B;
  stroke: #842323;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #D34040;
  stroke: #9F9F9F;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}

.st3 {
  fill: #932727;
}

.st4 {
  fill: #D34040;
}

.st5 {
  fill: #5B4343;
}

.first-tr-str0 {
  fill: #DDCCCC;
  stroke: #EAE5E5;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<defs>
    <filter id="blur" x="-1" y="-1" width="5" height="5">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="7" />
    </filter>
</defs>
<g>
        <path class="st0" d="M272.8,277.5h-56.2v-72.9c0-9.7,7.9-17.6,17.6-17.6h21c9.7,0,17.6,7.9,17.6,17.6V277.5z" />
        <line class="st1" x1="258.5" y1="187.5" x2="258.5" y2="275.5" />
        <line class="st1" x1="231.5" y1="188" x2="231.5" y2="276" />
        <rect x="200.6" y="275.9" class="st2" width="88" height="66" />
        <path class="st3" d="M252.5,275.5h-16V196c0-1.6,1.3-3,3-3h10.1c1.6,0,3,1.3,3,3V275.5z" />
        <circle class="st4" cx="244.5" cy="210.5" r="7.5" />
        <circle class="st5" cx="244.5" cy="210.5" r="4.5" />
        <rect width="5" height="20" x="212" y="210"/>
        <rect width="5" height="20" x="212" y="250"/>
        <rect width="5" height="20" x="272" y="210"/>
        <rect width="5" height="20" x="272" y="250"/>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="220.5" r="8.5" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 220.5;90 244.5 220.5" dur="1s" transform="scale(1.1)" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="246.5" cy="230.5" r="6" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 246.5 230.5;90 246.5 230.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="238.5" r="7" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 238.5;90 244.5 238.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="242.5" cy="245.5" r="4" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 242.5 245.5;360 242.5 245.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="250.5" r="9" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 250.5;90 244.5 250.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="246.5" cy="260.5" r="9" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 246.5 260.5;90 246.5 260.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="270.5" r="8" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 270.5;90 246.5 270.5" dur="1s" transform="scale(1.5)" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="242.5" cy="275.5" r="6" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 242.5 275.5;90 242.5 275.5" dur="1s" transform="scale(1.8)" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="242.5" cy="280.5" r="9" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 242.5 280.5;90 242.5 280.5" dur="1s" transform="scale(1.6)" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Почти готово, осталось соединить всё в одну конструкцию и сделать анимацию движения поезда по заданной траектории, используя `path`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.st0 {
  fill: #A82F2F;
  stroke: #9F9F9F;
}

.st1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  fill: #5B5B5B;
  stroke: #842323;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #D34040;
  stroke: #9F9F9F;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}

.st3 {
  fill: #932727;
}

.st4 {
  fill: #D34040;
}

.st5 {
  fill: #5B4343;
}

.first-tr-str0 {
  fill: #DDCCCC;
  stroke: #EAE5E5;
}
```

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<defs>    
    <filter id="blur" x="-1" y="-1" width="5" height="5">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" />
    </filter>
      <rect id="rect" width="95" height="20" fill="#663300" />
</defs>
<g>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="10"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="50"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="90"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="130"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="170"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="210"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="250"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="290"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="330"/>
  <use xlink:href="#rect" x="150" y="370"/>
</g>
    <g>
      <line x1="230" y1="400" x2="230" y2="0" stroke="#232b2b" stroke-width="5" />
      <line x1="165" y1="400" x2="165" y2="0" stroke="#232b2b" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <g id="train" transform="translate(-350 0)">
      <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M272.8,277.5h-56.2v-72.9c0-9.7,7.9-17.6,17.6-17.6h21c9.7,0,17.6,7.9,17.6,17.6V277.5z" />
        <line class="st1" x1="258.5" y1="187.5" x2="258.5" y2="275.5" />
        <line class="st1" x1="231.5" y1="188" x2="231.5" y2="276" />
        <rect x="200.6" y="275.9" class="st2" width="88" height="66" />
        <path class="st3" d="M252.5,275.5h-16V196c0-1.6,1.3-3,3-3h10.1c1.6,0,3,1.3,3,3V275.5z" />
        <circle class="st4" cx="244.5" cy="210.5" r="7.5" />
        <circle class="st5" cx="244.5" cy="210.5" r="4.5" />
        <rect width="5" height="20" x="212" y="210"/>
        <rect width="5" height="20" x="212" y="250"/>
        <rect width="5" height="20" x="272" y="210"/>
        <rect width="5" height="20" x="272" y="250"/>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="220.5" r="8.5" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 220.5;360 246.5 220.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="220.5" r="8.5" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 220.5;90 244.5 220.5" dur="1s" transform="scale(1.1)" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="246.5" cy="230.5" r="6" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 246.5 230.5;90 246.5 230.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="238.5" r="7" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 238.5;90 244.5 238.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="242.5" cy="245.5" r="4" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 242.5 245.5;360 242.5 245.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="250.5" r="9" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 250.5;90 244.5 250.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="246.5" cy="260.5" r="9" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 246.5 260.5;90 246.5 260.5" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="244.5" cy="270.5" r="8" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 244.5 270.5;90 246.5 270.5" dur="1s" transform="scale(1.5)" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="242.5" cy="275.5" r="6" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 242.5 275.5;90 242.5 275.5" dur="1s" transform="scale(1.8)" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
        <g>
          <circle cx="242.5" cy="280.5" r="9" fill="gray" filter="url(#blur)" />
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 242.5 280.5;90 242.5 280.5" dur="1s" transform="scale(1.6)" repeatCount="indefinite"
          />
        </g>
      <g>
        <rect width="10" height="9" x="240" y="341" />
        <rect width="90" height="150" x="200" y="350" fill="gray" rx="5" />
      </g>
      <g>
        <rect width="10" height="9" x="240" y="500" />
        <rect width="90" height="150" x="200" y="509" fill="gray" rx="5" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <path id="trainPath" style="fill:none;stroke: transparent;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
      d="m 302.80952,297 c 0,-97.08928571 0,-297.08928571 0,-997.08928571" />
    <animateMotion xlink:href="#train" begin="0s" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#trainPath" />
    </animateMotion>
  </svg>
```

**Update:**
Использовал `<use>` для оптимизации `SVG`

Связанный вопрос: [Как нарисовать автомобиль с помощью команд SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787246/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4-svg)