# Поиск ошибок в приложениях SVG

Tags: svg, анимация, smil

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На практике очень часто случается, что приложение `SVG` должно работать, фрагменты кода, как и в других работающих приложениях точно такие же, но любые попытки найти ошибку, заставить работать новое приложение не приносят результата.

- Какие есть наиболее часто встречающиеся ошибки в написании кода SVG?
- Какие есть практические способы диагностирования ошибок?
- Как избежать появления ошибок, делающих приложение svg
  неработоспособным?

. 
Использовано изображение https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ghostscript_Tiger.svg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Создание SVG приложения

1.1 Создавать и производить отладку SVG необходимо в родной среде, то есть в файле с расширением *.svg

Для примера возьмем очень короткий код и сохраним его в двух форматах:
 `Primer.html` и `Primer.svg`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="100"
viewBox="0 0 100 100" >  
 <rect  width="100px" height="100px" fill="skyblue">
</svg>
```

- При запуске `Primer.html` ничего не произойдёт,  прямоугольник 
  появится, но если вы будете его использовать дальше в приложении,
  например клонировать с помощью команды `<use>`, то будете долго
  искать ошибку,- почему не появляются копии прямоугольников.
- При запуске файла в формате `Primer.svg` парсер `SVG` выведет на
  экран сообщение об ошибке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сразу видно, что не закрыт тег `<rect> …… </rect>`

**1.2 Нужно ли указывать в шапке файла Namespace?**

Современные браузеры последних версий лояльно относятся, если не указано `Namespace` в шапке svg файла.

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

- Сообщений об ошибке парсер `HTML` не выдаст.
- Но, если запустить файл.svg с аналогичным кодом, то будет сообщение
  об ошибке – отсутствии `Namespace`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Так указывать или не указывать в шапке SVG Namespace?*

На положительное решение указывают факты, что возникают проблемы с использованием svg файлов, у которых не указаны в шапке `Namespace` при добавлении последних в`HTML` с помощью тегов `<img>` и `<object>`

Вывод – нужно обязательно добавлять в шапку svg файла Namespace.

### *Шаблон - заготовка файла SVG*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  

<rect x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%" fill="purple" />
</svg>
```

### 2. Решение проблем с видимостью элементов внутри SVG полотна

2.1 Создание видимой границы svg полотна для визуального контроля нахождения svg элементов.

Для этого создается рамка точно по границам видимого полотна svg c помощью простого правила `CSS` в шапке SVG файла: `style=”Border:1px solid red;”`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200"
viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="Border:2px solid red;" >  
 <circle  cx="100" cy="100" r="110" fill="yellowgreen"/>
</svg>
```

Без красной границы полотна svg у нас бы вызвало удивление, почему ожидаемый круг превратился в многоугольник.
Теперь видно, что круг вышел за границы svg полотна и его края были подрезаны.
Решение напрашивается само собой – уменьшить радиус окружности, как минимум до `r=”100″`

**2.2 Позиционирование с помощью команды transform=”translate(X Y)”**

Второй пример. Допустим имеем такой код:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200"
viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="Border:1px solid red;" >  
 <rect  x="150" y="10" width="200" height="200" fill="yellowgreen"/>
</svg>
```

Ширина квадрата должна быть `width=”200″`, но видимая часть намного тоньше, и сколько мы не увеличивали бы ширину, квадрат останется узким, потому-что выходит за пределы видимости.
Для возвращения элементов `SVG` в зону видимости существует команда `transform=”translate(X Y)”`, которая двигает изображение по осям координат.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200"
viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="Border:1px solid red;" >  
 <g transform="translate(-130 0)">
 <rect  x="150" y="10" width="150" height="200" fill="yellowgreen"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

### 3. Решение проблем видимости элементов с помощью графического редактора

Этот способ применяется в сложных случаях, когда элементы svg находятся вне зоны видимости и непонятно в какую сторону и насколько нужно перемещать их, чтобы они попали в зону видимости.
Допустим нам нужно использовать следующий файл svg:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" heght="200" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid red;">
 
<path id="svg_23" d="m448,1395.555556c0,0 62.222222,1.777777 62.222222,1.777777c0,0 78.222222,-72.888889 78.222222,-72.888889c0,0 -3.555555,-92.444444 -3.555555,-92.444444c0,0 -135.111111,0 -135.111111,0z" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Ничего нет. Все попытки поиска красной фигуры методом научного тыка, применяя команду перемещения изображения
 и подбора координат, скорее всего кроме разочарования ни к чему не приведут. Спасёт в этой ситуации любой векторный редактор.

3.1 Открываем файл в векторном редакторе и уменьшаем масштаб изображения до тех пор пока не найдется красная фигура.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Серый прямоугольник это зона видимости нашего svg файла. Чтобы переместить красную фигуру в зону видимости, нужно, как видно из рисунка, переместить её влево на `370px` и поднять вверх на `1170px`. Это можно сделать и другим способом,- используя координаты
`x-min`, `y-min` у `viewBox` 
Например: `viewBox=”370 1170 300 300″`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" heght="200" viewBox="370 1170 300 300" style="border:1px solid red;">
 
<path id="svg_23" d="m448,1395.555556c0,0 62.222222,1.777777 62.222222,1.777777c0,0 78.222222,-72.888889 78.222222,-72.888889c0,0 -3.555555,-92.444444 -3.555555,-92.444444c0,0 -135.111111,0 -135.111111,0z"  stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

### 4. Валидатор SVG

Можно проверять на валидность файлы svg, находящиеся в сети, на локальном компьютере или просто загрузить код в валидатор.

https://validator.w3.org

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень пригодится!