# Как правильно написать формулу path

Tags: html, svg

Встречаются разные формы записи `<path>`, например:

1. `<path d="M 10 210 L 110 10 L 210 210 z"/>`
2. `<path d="M10,210  110,10 210,210 z"/>`
3. `<path d="M 0 200 V 200 150 h 0 50 V 150 100 H 50 100 V 100 50 H 100 150 V 50 0 H 150 200 V 0 200 z"/>`
4. `<path d="M 0 200 v-50 h50 v-50 h50 v-50 h50 v-50 h50  v200 z"/>`
5. `<path d="M0,200v-50h50v-50h50v-50h50v-50h50v200z"/>`

Возникают вопросы :

Что означают буквы в формуле патча?
Когда нужно ставить запятые, а когда разделять координаты пробелами?
Почему одни и те же буквы пишутся в одном случае заглавными, а вдругих случаях маленькими буквами?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все приведенные в вопросе формы записи `path` правильные,- как вам удобно, так и пишите, соблюдая основное правило - **положительные числа координат в формуле патча должны быть разделены пробелами или запятыми, или буквами команд патча.**

### Буквенные команды формулы патча

Все буквенные команды патча, могут быть в верхнем и нижнем регистре. Верхний регистр указывает на то, что последующая координата абсолютная (absolute), а нижний – относительная (relative).

**M** – (moveto x,y)   – переместить указатель в точку с абсолютными координатами (x,y)
 Эти координаты считаются началом пути.

**m** – (relative) - относительное начало пути применяется для сложных, пересекающихся или параллельных путей. Другими словами, когда в одном патче несколько подпатчей.

**L** - (lineto) нарисовать линию от текущей точки к указанной с абсолютными координатами (x,y) *Эту команду можно не указывать, заменив её пробелом между соседними группами координат.*
**z** - замыкание контура. Патч будет замкнут, если координаты конечной и начальной точки пути будут совпадать. Можно не указывать координаты конечной точки и путь будет замкнут, если после координат предпоследней точки будет написана команда -`z`

Ниже пример кода и поясняющей графики:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="280" height="280" viewBox="0 10 300 300">
 <path d="M 10 210 L 110 10 L 210 210 z" fill="#9DE281" stroke-width="3" stroke="#FDD000"  />
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красная точка - это начальная точка `path` - `M 10 210`

`<path d="M 10 210 L 110 10 L 210 210 z"/>`

- M 10 210 – перемещаем перо в начальную точку точку х=”10″, y=”210″`
- L 110 10 – рисуем линию до точки х=”110″, y=”10″
- L 210 210 – рисуем линию до точки х=”210″, y=”210″
- замыкаем контур – “z”

### Горизонтальные  (H,h) и вертикальные (V,v) линии

**H** (horizontal lineto) - эта команда для рисования горизонтальных линий, последующие две цифры указывают горизонтальные координаты начала и конца линии.

**V** (vertical lineto) -  команда для рисования вертикальных линий, последующие две цифры указывают вертикальные координаты начала и конца линии.

Пример

Рисуем вертикальную линию из точки `M 110 210` в точку `V 110 10`.

`<path d="M 110 210  V 110 10" />`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В формуле патча обязательно должны быть указаны координаты начальной точки `M 110 210` или другой точки из которой будет нарисована вертикальная линия.

**Пример совместного использования вертикальных и горизонтальных линий.**

Допустим нужно нарисовать ступеньки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<path d="M 0 200 V 200 150 h 0 50 V 150 100 H 50 100 V 100 50 H 100 150 V 50 0 H 150 200 V 0 200 z"                         style="stroke:red; fill: greenyellow"/>
</svg>
```

Использование вертикальных и горизонтальных линий с абсолютными координатами, как в примере выше, заметно увеличивает код. При использовании относительных координат код становится намного короче, так как задается только относительная длина `h` от последней точки пути для горизонтальных линий и высота `v` для вертикальных линий. Сам процесс рисования становится проще, так как не нужно высчитывать абсолютные расстояния от начала координат.
 Для сравнения,- ниже код рисует те же ступеньки с использованием относительных величин `h` и `v` .

**Пример рисования с помощью относительных величин `h` и `v`**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<path d="M 0 200 v-50 h50 v-50 h50 v-50 h50 v-50 h50  v200 z" style="stroke:red; fill: greenyellow"/>
</svg>
```

*Так как начало координат `(0,0`) полотна `SVG` находится в левом верхнем углу, то положительное направление оси “X” будет вправо, а оси “Y” – вниз. Поэтому команда `v -50` соответствует перемещению вверх на `50px` от текущей точки по вертикали, а команда `h -60` влево на `60px` по горизонтали.*

Более подробно [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=897#comm_m) и [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

**Сокращенная формула записи патча**

Можно еще сократить код, убрав пробелы, между командами и цифрами. Для разделения положительных чисел применяется запятая.

`<path d="M0,200v-50h50v-50h50v-50h50v-50h50v200z"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<path d="M0,200v-50h50v-50h50v-50h50v-50h50v200z" style="stroke:red; fill: greenyellow"/>
</svg>
```